# Kubernetes(minikube) + React Frontend + .netcore api + Cluster IP service + ingress + net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-ingress

Not able to resolve an API hosted as a ClusterIP service on Minikube when calling from the React JS frontend.

The basic architecture of my application is as follows
React --> .NET core API

Both these components are hosted as ClusterIP services. I have created an ingress service with http paths pointing to React component and the .NET core API.

However when I try calling it from the browser, react application renders, but the call to the API fails with 
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Below are the .yml files for

---

### 1. React application

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: frontend-clusterip
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 59000
        targetPort: 3000
    selector:
    app: frontend
```

---

### 2. .NET core API

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: backend-svc-nodeport
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
    app: backend-svc
    ports:
    - port: 5901
        targetPort: 59001
```

---

### 3. ingress service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
    name: ingress-service
    annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /?(.*)
            backend: 
            serviceName: frontend-clusterip
            servicePort: 59000
        - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
            serviceName: backend-svc-nodeport
            servicePort: 5901
```

---

### 4. frontend deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: frontend
spec:
    selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: frontend
    replicas: 1
    template:
        metadata:
        labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: frontend
        image: upendra409/tasks_tasks.frontend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT"
            value: "Kubernetes"
        - name: "REACT_APP_BACKEND"
            value: "http://backend-svc-nodeport"
        - name: "REACT_APP_BACKENDPORT"
            value: "5901"
```

---

This is the error I get in the browser:

```
xhr.js:166 GET 
http://backend-svc-nodeport:5901/api/tasks net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I installed curl in the frontend container to get in the frontend pod to try to connect the backend API using the above URL, but the command doesn't work

```
C:\test\tasks [develop ≡ +1 ~6 -0 !]> kubectl exec -it frontend-655776bc6d-nlj7z --curl http://backend-svc-nodeport:5901/api/tasks

Error: unknown flag: --curl
```

Comment: the unknown flag curl is because you have no space between the double-dash and curl. It should be -- curl, instead of --curl.

Comment: Thank you Suren, now I am getting the response from the api. But the browser in the local machine still throws the same error

Comment: how are you making the request from the browser? You don't do `http://backend-svc-nodeport:5901/api/tasks` right?

Comment: @Upendra Hi, can you provide me with the following information: cluster enviroment, kubernetes version, network plugin and version.

Comment: @ Suren, I have a React JS frontend running in minikube.

Comment: @ Piotr, Cluster Env - Minikube, Version : v1.3.1. Not sure where can I find network plugin and version

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error from local machine because `ClusterIP` service is wrong type for accessing from outside of the cluster. As mentioned in kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) `ClusterIP` is only reachable from within the cluster.

> ### Publishing Services (ServiceTypes)
>
> For some parts of your application (for example, frontends) you may
>   want to expose a Service onto an external IP address, that’s outside
>   of your cluster.
>
> Kubernetes  `ServiceTypes`  allow you to specify what kind of Service
>   you want. The default is  `ClusterIP`.
>
> `Type`  values and their behaviors are:
>
> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the
>     cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`.
> - [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):
>     Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the 
>     `NodePort`). A  `ClusterIP`  Service, to which the  `NodePort` 
>     Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact
>     the  `NodePort`  Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting 
>     `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
> - [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer):
>     Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.
>     `NodePort`  and  `ClusterIP`  Services, to which the external load
>     balancer routes, are automatically created.
> - [`ExternalName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname):
>     Maps the Service to the contents of the  `externalName`  field (e.g. 
>     `foo.bar.example.com`), by returning a  `CNAME`  record
>
>   with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up.
>
>   > **Note:**  You need CoreDNS version 1.7 or higher to use the  `ExternalName`  type.

**I suggest using `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` service type instead.**

Refer to above documentation links for examples.